# No reverse match , как сделать редирект?

Tags: python, django

получаю ошибку Reverse for 'password_change_done' not found. При попытке сменить пароль , после отправки формы смены пароля , я думаю не происходит редирект , подскажите как это сделать , пытался добавить post_change_redirect в url но не сработало .

**urls**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path('change_password/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(),
         {'post_change_redirect': 'account:password_change_done'}, name='change_password'),
    path('change_password/done/', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='change_password_done'),

]
```

**password_change_form.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Change your password{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Chane your password</h1>
    <p>Use the form below to change password.</p>
    <form action="." method="post">
        {{form.as_p}}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Change"></p>
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**password_change_done**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Password changed{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Password changed</h1>
    <p>Your password has been successfully changed.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e6a4fc9da2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <span class="logo">Th<i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>nysocial</span>
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <ul class="menu">
                <li {% if section == "dashboard" %}  class="selected"{% endif %}>
                    <a href="{% url 'account:dashboard' %}">My dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li {% if section == "images" %} class="selected"{% endif %}>
                    <a href="#">Images</a>
                </li>
                <li {% if section == "people" %} class="selected"{% endif %}>
                    <a href="#">People</a>
                </li>
                 <li {% if section == "news" %} class="selected"{% endif %}>
                    <a href="#">News</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="user">
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                Hello {{ request.user.first_name }},
                <a href="{% url 'account:logout' %}">Logout</a>
            {% else %}
                <a href="{% url 'account:login' %}">Log-in</a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: думаю стоит добавить view.py чтобы понять в чем проблема

Comment: я использовал view предоставленные джанго для смены пароля , свои не писал

Comment: АХахахаха, ты по книге Дронова щас django учишь? Я щас тоже на этой станице XD

Comment: не , джанго 2 в примерах )

Comment: У тебя нет урла с именем `change_password`

Comment: проблема решена)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у кого-то будет подобная ошибка  , импоритруйте reverse_lazy и передавайте явно пространство имен в аргументах:

```py
path('password-change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('account:password_change_done')), name='password_change')
```